# Rudin's RCA, Theorem $4.11$.

Tags: analysis, hilbert-spaces

This is the definition which we need for the proof:
[image]

There is the theorem:
Let $M$ be a closed subspace of a Hilbert space $H$.

$(a)$ every $x$ $\in$ $H$ has then a unique decomposition

$x$ $=$ $Px$ $+$ $Qx$

into a sum of $Px$ $\in$ $M$ and $Qx$ $\in$ $M^\bot$.

$(b)$ $Px$ and $Qx$ are the nearest points to $x$ in $M$ and in $M^\bot$, respectively.

$(c)$ The mappings $P$ : $H$ $\rightarrow$ $M$ and $Q$ : $H$ $\rightarrow$ $M^\bot$ are linear.

$(d)$ $||x||^2$ $=$ $||Px||^2$ $+$ $||Qx||^2$.

There is the corollary theorem:

If $M$ $\neq$ $H$, then there exists $y$ $\in$ $H$, $y$ $\neq$ $0$, such that $y$ $\bot$ $M$.

P and Q are called the orthogonal projections of $H$ onto $M$ and $M^\bot$.

There is the proof of the $(a)$ :

As regards the uniqueness in $(a)$, suppose that $x'$ $+$ $y'$ $=$ $x"$ $+$ $y"$ for some vectors $x'$, $x"$, in $M$ and $y'$, $y"$, in $M^\bot$.

Then

$x'$ - $x"$ $=$ $y"$ $-$ $y'$.

Since $x'$ $-$ $x"$ $\in$ $M$, $y"$ $-$ $y'$ $\in$ $M^\bot$, and $M$ $\cap$ $M^\bot$ $=$ {$0$} [ an immediate consequence of the fact that $(x,x)$ $=$ implies $x$ $=$ $0$],
wee have $x"$ $=$ $x'$,  $y"$ $=$ $y'$.

I have two questions:

$(1)$ how do  $(a)$, $(b)$, $(c)$, $(d)$ imply the corollary theorem: If $M$ $\neq$ $H$, then there exists $y$ $\in$ $H$, $y$ $\neq$ $0$, such that $y$ $\bot$ $M$ ?

and why P and Q are called the orthogonal projections of $H$ onto $M$ and $M^\bot$ ?

$(2)$ :

I don't understand how do we get $M$ $\cap$ $M^\bot$ $=$ {$0$} and therefore how do we conclude from there that
$x"$ $=$ $x'$,  $y"$ $=$ $y'$ ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $M\neq H$, take $z\in H\setminus M$. The theorem gives $z=Pz+Qz$ with $Pz\in M$ and $Qz\in M^\bot$. We must have $Qz\neq 0$, since otherwise $z=Px\in M$. The $y=Qz$ proves the corollary.

Comment: If $x\in M\cap M^\bot$, then $x$ is orthogonal to all elements of $M$ (since it belongs to $M^\bot$) and to all elements of $M^\bot$ (since it belongs to $M$). But then $x\cdot x=x\cdot(Px+Qx)=x\cdot Px + x\cdot Qx=0$, which implies $x=0$

Comment: @owl and why is $x’$ equal of $x’’$ and $y’$ equal of $y’’$ ?

Comment: $x'-x''\in M\cap M^\bot=\{0\}$

Comment: @owl An alternative proof for 2, not using $P$ and $Q$: If $x\in M\cap M^\bot$, then, by definition of $M^\bot$, $x$ is orthogonal to all elements of $M$, in particular to $x$ itself. So $x\cdot x=0$, which implies $x=0$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Oh wow. Brilliant. Here is a medal for your ground breaking discovery. Repeating the same argument. Some people just like the sound of their own voice.

Comment: @owl In my opinion, an argument that invokes the definition of $M^\bot$ twice and then uses the decomposition $x=Px+Qx$ is different from an argument that invokes the definition once and doesn't involve $P$ and $Q$ at all.

Comment: @owl we know that $x' - x''$ $\in$ $M$ not $M$ $\cap$ $M^\bot$

Comment: @JohnNash $x'-x''=y''-y'\in M^\bot$

Comment: @owl thank you man.  and why P and Q are called the orthogonal projections of $H$ onto $M$ and $M^\bot$ ? can you answer on this too pls?

Comment: [Projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)), because $P^2x=Px$ and $Q^2x=Qx$. So, each element of $H$ gets squashed down to $M$  and $M^\bot$, respectively, but once they are there they are not moved around anymore.  Orthogonal, because $x-Px\bot M$ and $x-Qx\bot M^\bot$. This means that $x\mapsto Px$ is translating $x$ by a vector $x-Px$ that is perpendicular to $M$. Similarly $x\to Qx$ is translating $x$ by a vector $x-Qx$ that is perpendicular to $M^\bot$.

Comment: This a generalization of what you do when you take a point on a Cartesian coordinate plane and drop perpendiculars from it to the axes to find its components in the directions of each axis and with them its coordinates.

Comment: @owl why is $x$ $-$ $Px$ orthogonal to $M$? and why is $x$ - $Qx$ orthogonal to $M^\bot$?

Comment: $x-Px=Qx\in M^\bot$, which are all orthogonal to all elements of $M$.

Comment: Adding reference to related question on the same Theorem, so that they are linked: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4619805/papa-rudin-theorem-4-11-c-and-d?rq=1