# Papa Rudin Theorem $4.11$ $(c)$ and $(d)$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces

This is the definition which we need for the proof:
[image]

There is the theorem:
Let $M$ be a closed subspace of a Hilbert space $H$.

$(a)$ every $x$ $\in$ $H$ has then a unique decomposition

$x$ $=$ $Px$ $+$ $Qx$

into a sum of $Px$ $\in$ $M$ and $Qx$ $\in$ $M^\bot$.

$(b)$ $Px$ and $Qx$ are the nearest points to $x$ in $M$ and in $M^\bot$, respectively.

$(c)$ The mappings $P$ : $H$ $\rightarrow$ $M$ and $Q$ : $H$ $\rightarrow$ $M^\bot$ are linear.

$(d)$ $||x||^2$ $=$ $||Px||^2$ $+$ $||Qx||^2$.

There is the proof of $(c)$ :

If we apply $(a)$ to $x$,to $y$, and to $\alpha$$x$ $+$ $\beta$$y$, we obtain

$P(\alpha x + \beta y ) $ $-$ $\alpha$$P$$x$ $-$ $\beta$$P$$y$ $=$ $\alpha$$Q$$x$ $+$ $\beta$$Q$$y$ $-$ $Q(\alpha x + \beta y)$.

The left side is in $M$, the right side in $M^\bot$.

Hence both are $0$, so $P$ and $Q$ are linear.
Since $Px$ $\bot$ $Qx$, $(d)$ follows from $(a)$.

I have two questions:

$(1)$

How do we get  this equality :
$P(\alpha x + \beta y ) $ $-$ $\alpha$$P$$x$ $-$ $\beta$$P$$y$ $=$ $\alpha$$Q$$x$ $+$ $\beta$$Q$$y$ $-$ $Q(\alpha x + \beta y)$ ?
and why are both left and right sides $0$ ? And why does the fact that both sides are equal of $0$ imply that $P$ and $Q$ are linear?

$(2)$

I don't understand how does $(d)$ follow from $(a)$ ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(\alpha x+\beta y)+Q(\alpha x+\beta y)=\alpha x+\beta y=\alpha(P(x)+Q(x))+\beta(P(y)+Q(y))$$Implies: $$P(\alpha x+\beta y)-\alpha P(x)-\beta P(y)=\alpha Q(x)+\beta Q(y)- Q(\alpha x+\beta y)$$

Both sides are elements of the linearly disjoint spaces $M$ and $M^{\perp}$. The only element of $M\cap M^{\perp}$ is the zero vector: hence I can deduce: $$P(\alpha x+\beta y)-\alpha P(x)-\beta P(y)=0=\alpha Q(x)+\beta Q(y)-Q(\alpha x+\beta y)$$By basic addition: $$P(\alpha x+\beta y)=\alpha P(x)+\beta P(y),\,Q(\alpha x+\beta y)=\alpha Q(x)+\beta Q(y)$$Follows. All variables were arbitrary, hence $P,Q$ are linear.

(d) is *Pythagoras' theorem*. It follows from (a) and from the orthogonal relation: $$\|x\|^2=\langle x,x\rangle=\langle Px+Qx,Px+Qx\rangle=\langle Px,Px\rangle+\langle Qx,Qx\rangle+0=\|Px\|^2+\|Qx\|^2$$